# How to make script running when logging/logout from current user.?

Tags: scripting

I have a raspberry pi. It has a user pi to which we automatically login on every boot. I need to rename the pi to myuser. To do this, I am following the below steps:

1. sudo passwd root -> Assign a password to root user
2. sudo reboot
3. Login as root
4. Run commands `usermod -l myuser pi` `usermod -m -d /home/myuser myuser`
5. sudo reboot
6. Login as myuser
7. Edit the file `/etc/sudoers` and change pi to myuser

Following above steps will change the pi user to myuser.

I need to make a script of this. But the problem I am facing is how to keep the script running when rebooting and logging in as root/pi. For example, to login as root and can logout from the pi by using the command

`sudo pkill -u pi`

This will logout from pi and a login screen appears when I can login as root by entering username (root) and password. But then after login as root, how can I keep my script running so that it can run commands `usermod -l myuser pi` `usermod -m -d /home/myuser myuser`. Is there any way of doing this, or any alternative way of doing changing username.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem you're running into is that you're trying to modify the user account that you're logged in as. That could be a little tricky. But you could try something like the following:

```bsh
# Become the root user (if you aren't already)
sudo su

# Set the password for the root user
echo "root:<PASSWORD>" | chpasswd

# Update the system user-datbase files to reflect the name-change
sed -i 's/pi/myuser/g' /etc/passwd
sed -i 's/pi/myuser/g' /etc/shadow
sed -i 's/pi/myuser/g' /etc/group

# Update the sudoers file to reflect the name-change
sed -i /etc/sudoers 's/pi/myuser/g'

# Move the user home directory to the new location (the UID stays the same, we don't need to run chown)
mv -i /home/pi /home/newuser
```

If you want to run this non-interactively while you're logged in as the `pi` user, you can create the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# update_user.sh

# Set the password for the root user
echo "root:<PASSWORD>" | chpasswd

# Update the system user-datbase files to reflect the name-change
sed -i 's/pi/myuser/g' /etc/passwd
sed -i 's/pi/myuser/g' /etc/shadow
sed -i 's/pi/myuser/g' /etc/group

# Update the sudoers file to reflect the name-change
sed -i /etc/sudoers 's/pi/myuser/g'

# Move the user home directory to the new location (the UID stays the same, we don't need to run chown)
mv -i /home/pi /home/newuser
```

And then run it using `sudo` like this:

```bsh
sudo update_user.sh
```

**NOTE:** I think it's probably not a good idea to have a shell script lying around which contains your root password. You might want to consider *not* setting the root password programmatically like this.

My original solution is below.

---

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure why you have to reboot the device repeatedly. You should be able to make all of the changes that you want and then reboot when you're done. How about trying something like the following:

```bsh
# Become the root user (if you aren't already)
sudo su

# Set the password for the root user
passwd

# Change the login name of the "pi" user to "myuser"
usermod -l myuser pi

# Update the "myuser" home directory
usermod -m -d /home/myuser myuser

# Edit the file /etc/sudoers and change pi to myuser
visudo

# Reboot the system
reboot
```

This is a mild alteration of the list of commands that you're using: `sudo su` first, execute all of the commands, and only reboot once you're done. This still isn't scriptable in its current form, since it requires user interaction - specifically to set the password and edit the sudoers file. If you really want to be able to run this unattended then you would need to automate those two tasks. If that's your goal, then you might want to modify the script to look more like the following:

```bsh
# Become the root user (if you aren't already)
sudo su

# Set the password for the root user
echo "root:<PASSWORD>" | chpasswd

# Change the login name of the "pi" user to "myuser"
usermod -l myuser pi

# Update the "myuser" home directory
usermod -m -d /home/myuser myuser

# Edit the file /etc/sudoers and change pi to myuser (CAREFUL!)
sed -i /etc/sudoers 's/pi/myuser/g'

# Reboot the system
reboot
```

See this post for further discussion about setting or changing passwords programmatically:

- [Changing a linux password via script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837674/changing-a-linux-password-via-script)

Comment: I have tried the way which you have shown. I did execute the commands `usermod`  after `sudo su` but the commands say `pi is already used in the process`. Thats why we need to logout from pi and login as root to execute `usermod` command.

Comment: Can you not log in as root?

Comment: I can log in as root. But then scripting wont be possible. Because if I run a script from pi user i had to log out and log in as root then that script will exit because pi user session will expirer when you log out from pi and log in as root

Comment: What I meant was, can you not log in as root inititally (without logging in as "pi")? Also, could you describe how you're logging in to the system? Are you using ssh? Also, where do you want to run this script? On the target system itself, or on some other host?

Comment: Yes I think I can login as a root initially. And i guess if I logged in as root initially i would be able execute commands edit the visudo file in the root user. I will try this and will update you. I am running the script on target system and I am not using ssh. I am accessing the direct terminal

Comment: Right. I think the problem you were running into is that it might be fundamentally tricky to modify the currently logged in user. If you can avoid logging in as that user altogether then that will make things simpler. That said, take a look at my update. I added something that might work even if you have to initially log in as the "pi" user.

Comment: Your first approach is great. It works but the only issue is we cannot run `sudo su` from the script because after the sudo su, the shell will change and then the further commands will not run. Do you have any idea on how to run sudo su from the script.? I also cannot use sudo with all the sed commands because it will ask for password everytime which I do not want.

Comment: Remind me again, why can't you log in as root before running the script? Or why you can't run the script itself using the sudo command?

Comment: Are you using some sort of provisioning or orchestration tool here? What do you mean when you say that you "automatically" log into the machine when it boots?

Comment: Raspberry pi has a pi user and a root user. Root user do not have any password and the pi user has a password. When the raspberry pi boots it automatically logs and boots in pi user.

Comment: But anyways I have found a solution to the problem by using your first approach. In the script i will check which user is logged in currently by issuing command whoami or id. If the pi is logged in i will exit the script saying you need to run this script using root. So in this way user will then run sudo su and then will start the script to change the username. I have actually not implemented this but I think this will work. What do you think.? Btw thanks for your help. :)

Comment: That sounds fine to me. You can also run the script using sudo, i.e.: `sudo script.sh`

Comment: I've updated my solution to include this usage. Honestly though, I'm not sure that I see a whole lot of benefit to this approach. If I were you I would just set the `root` password then log out of the `pi` user, log back in as root, and then run these commands (or run the script).

Comment: These are actually for the people who do not know much about linux and its commands. Thats the reason i wanted to make it complete automatic. But thanks for your help.